Unable to configure logging for Scrapy
Based on scrapy documentatnion I configured some logging settings:
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s [%(name)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

It looks like it does not work.
What I would expect, there will be only INFO logs with defined LOG and DATE format but it does not work, this is an example of some logs:
DEBUG:scrapy.utils.log:Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
DEBUG:scrapy.utils.log:Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop
DEBUG:spidername:URL: https://www.somepage.com/123123123

I tried also LOG_ENABLED = False but it does not work at all.
I tried this:
logging.getLogger('scrapy').setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('asyncio').setLevel(logging.INFO)

But it also does not work and this is some logs example:
DEBUG:scrapy.utils.log:Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
DEBUG:scrapy.utils.log:Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop

Only way to change "something" is this:
logging.basicConfig(
    format=LOG_FORMAT,
    level=logging.INFO,
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
)

This changed only LOG and DATE format, but there are still DEBUG logs. If I want to configure Spider log level, I have to do it in spider with self.logger.setLevel(LOG_LEVEL).
Why settings works only partially and how to fix this? I do not want to configure multiple loggers in multiple places. It looks like best practice of python logging is not working here.
Scrapy version: 2.11.2
EDIT1:
I configured this settings in module settings:
settings
├── __init__.py
├── local.py  # this file is empty
├── settings.py # scrapy setting file
├── myapp.py # app config
└── ua.py # UA config

__init__.py looks like this:
from .settings import * # noqa
from .myapp import * # noqa

# Import local config if exists
try:
    from .local import * # noqa
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pass
except Exception:
    raise

Other settings works, e.g. logging to file, or configuration for my app or even User Agent config. Just some configuration from settings.py works and some not.
Spider is run with command scrapy crawl myspider

You need to describe how you are running your spider and where are you putting those settings and basicConfig calls, because the easiest answer is "your settings are not loaded".

Hi @wRAR, my settings are loaded as I described in my question, some parameters working (e.g. logging.basicConfig), some are not (e.g. LOG_ENABLED = False). I will add more information which could help.

maybe use print() to see which part of code is executed. You could also run without try/except to see if it has problem to import some modules.
